# Return in a loop Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, return

My JS-Code:

```
function getmaxtrophie(list) {
    for(var i =0;i<77;i++) {
        if (list[i].progress !== 100) {
            return list[i];
        }   
    }
}
def createTrophy(name, description, progress, time):
        trophy = {
            "name": name,
            "time": time,
            "description": description,
            "progress": progress
```

FirstObject of my list:
0: {…}
description: "Absolviere dein erstes Training"
name: "Jetzt geht’s los"
progress: 100
time: "2017-09-14T16:19:08.000Z"

If i Log mylist.progress im getting the right results , so it has to be my function thats destroying it right?

When I check the result of my function , the Log always says Undefined.
I thought return would exit the loop, and therefor a list element (list[i]) should be the return value.
No idea why it is not working.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you're passing as `list` to this function?

Comment: `if(typeof list[i] !== 'object' || list[i] instanceof Array)` that would be a problem.

Comment: done, soory should have done that from the start

Comment: @PHPglue soory did not quiet get that

Comment: That's an Array. You want a `.progress` property. You would have to have an Object that is not an Array for that.

Comment: Chris, I don't understand your data set. Can you give us a real life example of the `list` you pass, not of your "typ" as you put it. It looks like an array of array of arrays. Where is `progress` ever defined?

It would work fine if you give it the correct data type. I even rewrote it to be more succinct. I also didn't understand your arbitrary for loop of checking 77 times? https://jsfiddle.net/e8Lnb42o/

Comment: @PHPglue the list[i].progress gets me the Int.

Comment: Show us your actual list, or something so close we know what you're talking about.

Comment: @jas7457 .progress gets me an Int , and i can do this to the list with the right results..

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getmaxtrophie`, not all paths return a value: your return statement may not be hit, in this case, your function will return `undefined`.

Try this function to highlight the problem :

```
function getmaxtrophie(list) {
    for(var i =0;i<77;i++) {
        if (list[i].progress !== 100) {
            return list[i];
        }   
    }
    throw 'No item found';
}
```

I also encourage you to take profit of the array prototype:

```
const firstItemWithInterestingProgress = list.find(item => item.progress !== 100); //firstItemWithInterestingProgress  may be undefined
```

PS: What you intended to achieve looks weird.

Comment: tried it both ways, with youre function i still get the undefined call.... with the     const i get the Erroro code: ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `firstItemWithInterestingProgress' before initialization

Comment: Believe me, this is an between keyboard and chair error. Use a breakpoint and run the code step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your createTrophy definition and it seems to work now. You can see how I'm defining a sample mylist below.

```
function createTrophy(name, description, progress, time) {
 return {
     "name": name,
     "time": time,
     "description": description,
     "progress": progress
     };

}

var mylist = new Array(100);

mylist[0] = { progress: 100, description: 'test', name: 'basic', time: '2017-09-14T16:19:08.000Z' };

mylist[1] = { progress: 100, description: 'test2', name: 'basic2', time: '2017-09-14T16:19:09.000Z' };             

mylist[2] = createTrophy('basic3', 'test3', 55, '2017-09-14T16:19:10.000Z');

document.write( getmaxtrophie(mylist).progress );
```

Here is the output:

```
55
```

Comment: Dont see how youre createTrophy differs from mine , sure I see the the different syntax but yeah.... mh this looks pretty good does it also work if you remove the .progress in youre document.write?

Comment: You can't document.write the entire object because it expects an integer, string, etc such as .progress.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was my Brain not working with this lack of sleep.
I messed it up in my Main.

I Wrote:

```
`maxprogressiontrophie=sortlist.getmaxtrophie`
```

instead of:

```
maxprogressiontrophie=getmaxtrophie(sortlist);
```

and overlooked it like 7000 Times, combined with the dump call not to Upload my whole code to you guys!
I'm sorry but thanks for youre responses.